# JavaScript: Secure Random Number Generation

Tags: javascript, random, cryptography

I need to generate secure random numbers using JS.
This random number generation **must be as secure as possible(as random as possible)**.
So I clearly can't use Math.random() here.
AFAIK my best choice is to use Crypto API's **crypto.getRandomValues()** method.

I read that Crypto API is 'as secure as it gets'(apart from a 'true' RNG) and seeded with values taken from a platform-specific RNG like `/dev/urandom`(in unix).

**1. Is crypto.getRandomValues() really secure? Are there any flaws I should worry about?**

**2. Secure or insecure, should I take Crypto.getRandomValues()'s randomness any further? Like,**

I can use crypto.getRandomValues() again to get a random value from the first result of crypto.getRandomValues().

OR

I can implement my own RNG that uses user mouse movements/time/window width/height as seed.
Then use random numbers from that RNG to randomly select a number from the result of crypto.getRandomValues().

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question, I believe you should use crypto.getRandomValues as the other option (user mouse movements/time/window width/height) is tracable, and any experienced, good hacker will pose a risk to your system.

But what kind of "number" are you looking for?

Comment: I would be using crypto.getRandomValues() either way. The two options I've showed are ways I think to make it 'more' random. For instance I could use crypto.getRandomValues() twice. First to get an array of random values and then again to get a random value which then can be used to get a random value from the previously generated array. I hope it's clear. I'll show what I mean in code, that way more people will understand I think.